# C# (outlook add-in) context menu on folders

Tags: c#, events, outlook

In my VSTO outlook addin I'm trying to put a button that will show up when i right click on a folder. In my Startup function I have this:

```
Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
myApp.FolderContextMenuDisplay += new ApplicationEvents_11_FolderContextMenuDisplayEventHandler(myApp_FolderContextMenuDisplay);
```

then i have the handler for that...

```
void myApp_FolderContextMenuDisplay(CommandBar commandBar, MAPIFolder Folder)
{
    var contextButton = commandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, true) as CommandBarButton;
    contextButton.Visible = true;
    contextButton.Caption = "some caption...";
    contextButton.Click += new _CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(contextButton_Click);
}
```

and finally the handler for click....

```
void contextButton_Click(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    //stuff here
}
```

My question is how do I send that `MAPIFolder Folder` from `myApp_FolderContextMenuDisplay` to `contextButton_Click` ?

(If this can be done another way, I'm open for suggestions too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is just to use a closure, for example:

```
// where Folder is a local variable in scope, such as code in post
contextButton.Click += (CommandBarButton ctrl, ref bool cancel) => {
   DoReallStuff(ctrl, Folder, ref cancel);
};
```

Make sure to clean up the event, if required. One thing to watch out for is that the RCW for the Folder may now have an "extended lifetime" as the closure may keep it alive longer than before (but with the OOM is is *very important* to manually release the RCWs when not needed.)

Happy coding.