# VSTO customise outlook folder context menu

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am basically looking to do this:
[C# (outlook add-in) context menu on folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623209/c-sharp-outlook-add-in-context-menu-on-folders)

But the problem is the it never fires the FolderContextMenuDisplay event.
Looking at the documentation it seems to be deprecated, but does anyone know what I should use instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By using Ribbon XML you can set the visibility of context menu.

In this post, I will show you how to show and hide items in a context menu by using Ribbon XML. 
The context menu appears when a user right-clicks an Outlook folder.

First, add a Ribbon XML item to your Outlook project.

Then add the following code to your ThisAddIn class. This example assumes that your Ribbon is called Ribbon1 and that you are using C#:

```
  protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()   
    {    
        return new Ribbon1();    
    }
```

Next, replace the contents of the Ribbon1.xml file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
    <contextMenus>
        <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuFolder">
            <button idMso="FolderPropertiesContext" getVisible="IsVisible" />
        </contextMenu>
    </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

But wait. There’s more!
In Ribbon1.cs file create this method.

```
 public bool IsVisible(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
string name = ((Outlook.Folder)control.Context).Name;
        if (foldername == "Inbox")
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

When user right-clicks the folder, then we tell Outlook to not show the command by returning false. Otherwise, we tell Outlook to go ahead and make the command visible by returning true.

Comment: Hello NAJ
If this is useful then please mark the comment.